# Deep Links navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I want to use deep links with Jetpack Compose's Nav Host and followed this page on Compose Navigation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks

My implementation:
AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<application ...>
    <activity
    ...
    android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xkcd.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.xkcd.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`MainActivity.onCreate().setContent{}`

```kotlin
val rootUri = "https://www.xkcd.com"
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "mainView") {
    composable("mainView", deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink { uriPattern = rootUri })) {
        MainContent()
    }
    composable(
        route = "singleView/{number}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("number") { type = NavType.IntType }),
        deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink { uriPattern = "$rootUri/{number}" })
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        val number = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("number")
        SingleView(number)
    }
}
```

If I now click on a corresponding link the app opens but the navigation doesn't work

Comment: Check the log messages. There is probably one that indicates an unrecognized path.

Comment: @Johann there is no log message that seems to have to do anything with deep links or navigation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is with the Activity [launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode):

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#handle) says that is strongly recommended to always use the default `launchMode` of `standard` when using Navigation. When using standard launch mode, Navigation automatically handles deep links by calling [handleDeepLink()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#handleDeepLink(android.content.Intent)) to process any explicit or implicit deep links within the Intent. However, this does not happen automatically if the Activity is re-used when using an alternate `launchMode` such as `singleTop`. In this case, it is necessary to manually call `handleDeepLink()` in `onNewIntent()`, as shown in the following example:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    navController.handleDeepLink(intent)
}
```

Comment: How do you get instance navController onNewIntent when you use compose and navController is inside of setContent ?

Comment: @Kamil declare `navController` as a `lateinit var` in the activity's scope, set it in the `setContent`. It would be accessible throughout the activity; why did 8 people upvote this question of a comment?

Answer (score 2):

you also can do this

```
setContent {
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            val listener = Consumer<Intent> {
                //do som
            }
            addOnNewIntentListener(listener)
            onDispose { removeOnNewIntentListener(listener) }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Very helpful, as imo this is cleaner than having to keep a reference of the `navController` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by removing

```xml
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

from the manifest

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit different approach. I need to handle incoming intents in activity's `onCreate`:

```
fun onCreate() {
    setContent {
         // ... nav controller initialization
    }
    // ...
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        processCallerIntent(intent)
    }
}
```

and in `onNewIntent` method:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    processCallerIntent(intent)
}
```

And in my case `navController` initialization happens after `processCallerIntent` gets called with new intent.

That's why I implemented this via `viewModel.liveData` solution.

In the `processCallerIntent` method I save navigation route to be processed later:

```
private fun processCallerIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    if (intent == null) {
        return
    }

    if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_VIEW && /*...*/ ) {
        // Do all required checks and get navigation route you need
        viewModel.postPendingNavigationRoute(/*...*/)
    }
}
```

In `viewModel` I have something like this:

```
private val _pendingNavigationRoute = MutableLiveData<String>()
val pendingNavigationRoute: LiveData<String> = _pendingNavigationRoute

fun postPendingNavigationRoute(route: String) {
    _pendingNavigationRoute.value = route
}

fun clearPendingNavigationRoute() {
    _pendingNavigationRoute.value = ""
}
```

And in the root composabe I have something like this:

```
val pendingNavigationRoute by viewModel.pendingNavigationRoute.observeAsState()
LaunchedEffect(pendingNavigationRoute) {
    val route = pendingNavigationRoute
    if (!route.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        navController.navigate(route)
        viewModel.clearPendingNavigationRoute()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Kamil, you could save navController to viewModel, then reuse it inside onNewIntent method.

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val model: MainModel by viewModels()

    setContent {
      val navController = rememberNavController()
      model.navController = navController

      MyTheme {
        Scaffold {
          NavigationComponent(navController)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    val model: MainModel by viewModels()

    model.navController.handleDeepLink(intent)
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a great idea for testing purposes.

Comment: Richard, any better solusions are welcome here :)

Comment: Already posted under Kamil's comment.